# Find all k-length subsets efficiently in Elixir

Tags: combinations, elixir, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find all `k`-length subsets of a list in Elixir. Doing this in Python would be easy, but this is a purely functional language and I'm lost.

Input and output are lists right now, but they could be converted to `MapSet` or similar if needed. Order of output is not important.

```
choose([1,2,3], 0) = [[]]
choose([1,2,3], 1) = [[1], [2], [3]]
choose([1,2,3], 2) = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
choose([1,2,3], 3) = [[1,2,3]]
choose([1,2,3], 4) undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite Erlang combinations algorithm in Elixir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585697/how-to-rewrite-erlang-combinations-algorithm-in-elixir)

Comment: Do you require the final output to be a list? An `Enumerable` _might_ be faster (and definitely use lesser memory) if all you want is to iterate over the combinations.

Comment: An `Enumerable` would also work. It's easy to turn into a `List` if needed.