# Elixir built-in combinations method?

Tags: elixir, combinations

```
defmodule Itertools
    def combinations(_, 0), do: [[]] 
    def combinations([], _), do: [] 
    def combinations([h|t], m) do 
        (for l <- combinations(t, m-1), do: [h|l]) ++ combinations(t, m) 
    end 
end
```

I am working with a nested loop over an array that can be handled by something like Python's itertools.combinations, but don't see one in the standard library.  Does elixir have it built-in somewhere, or is there a better way to simulate a triangular loop over a list in Elixir?

I got the above code from rosettacode.org btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite Erlang combinations algorithm in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585697/how-to-rewrite-erlang-combinations-algorithm-in-elixir)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar with Erlang, Elixir do not have built-in function to do combinations. As Rosettacode said ‘This Elixir code just converted from Erlang’:

```rb
defmodule RC do
  def comb(0, _), do: [[]]
  def comb(_, []), do: []
  def comb(m, [h|t]) do
    (for l <- comb(m-1, t), do: [h|l]) ++ comb(m, t)
  end
end

{m, n} = {3, 5}
list = for i <- 1..n, do: i
Enum.each(RC.comb(m, list), fn x -> IO.inspect x end)
```

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Elixir

Comment: Please do not post answers containing links only. The reference might become broken, obsoleting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in method for doing this, but the [`Comb`](https://github.com/tallakt/comb) package on GitHub can do it.

You'll of course need to add it to your `mix.exs` dependencies:

```
[
  {:comb, git: "https://github.com/tallakt/comb.git", tag: "master"}
]
```

Then you can use it like this (taken from the above-linked GitHub docs):

```
iex> combinations(1..3, 2) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

iex> combinations([1, 1, 2, 2], 3) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
```

It also supports Cartesian products:

```
iex> cartesian_product(1..2, 3..4)
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```